# How to make a DIY bevel shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Sheep-It Render Farm doesn't support the bevel node (yet). Is it possible to construct a custom node setup that does the same thing as the bevel shader?

Comment: Nope! Sorry bro, unless you feel like some *intense* programming, this isn't possible 

Answer (score 2):

## Baking Normals

You could try baking the bevel to normal maps.

[image: Bake]

Comment: Is this on 16bit tangent maps or just 8 bit ones?

Comment: I assumed resources might be limited(SheepIt limits file size to 500MB) so 8 bit.

Comment: I tried 32 bits as well out of curiosity, it seems to me it has more to do with the resolution of the maps. The problems seem to go away with higher resolution and color depth, but it seems to me Object Space might let one get away with lower resolution and color depth.

Comment: You know what - I cannot reproduce it any more. I have no idea what is going on. Must be my mistake somewhere.

Comment: You cant output a 16bit depth map and then convert it in 8bit with dithering. Works ok. Maybe consider using an additionnal UV set for your bevels, otherwise you will use only 10% of the texture space for marking bevels while 90% will be purely flat blue.

Comment: I think that was meant to be quick and dirty, because if you are going through the trouble of UV mapping only beveled parts, then, why not make the bevels with geometry?.. Converting to 8 bits would not be an issue, but it's probably a good idea to try to avoid any processing for UV maps - even resizing them in Photoshop with Bicubic Sharper algorithm could make the values wrong. Personally I think if 8 bit normal maps are not good enough, it should be geometry instead - if you can spot the difference between 8 and 16 bits, the normal map is overdone already, but that's just an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You could try with an OSL shader, maybe.
Google "OSL bevel shader Blender" or have a look here:
https://lesterbanks.com/2014/03/blender-osl-bevel-shader/

Comment: But are OSL scripts supported by Sheepit ? (EDIT : looks like it does: https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1351&p=6174&hilit=osl#p6174 )

Comment: OSL shaders are comepletely integrated into Blender, wouldnt know why they shouldn't. Please do not link to offsite sites that need registration, there is no use for 90% of people who are looking through here, as they are probably not registered there..

Comment: A lot of things are not supported or disabled on Sheep-It, including custom scripts. OSL materials being made of scripts, that's why I was wondering. I couldn't find any answer to that question anywhere but on Sheep-it forum. So if anyone wants to see where my statement come from, he can. Otherwise, well I can't do blackmagic.